# How to find the programming done for cells / worksheets in Excel, to be able to set precision?

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

I have a drawing in SolidEdge software, where the dimensions of the drawing are exported to Microsoft Excel. It has a column where various dimensions of the drawing are given in various forms in every row. Eg: `Length` is specified as `w 9.2` (and this is a numeric cell). `Straightness` is specified as `a\0.015]` (and this is also a numeric cell), `Length` specified as `15.00` and so on...

When I click the `15.00` cell, the formula bar shows it as 15. When I try converting this cell to a `Text` cell and then try editing the number, I get an error message saying "The value you entered is not valid. A user has restricted values that can be entered into this cell".

**What I'd like to know:**
**1.** How can I see the scripting done for this worksheet, so that I can change the settings for any particular cell? I'm assuming that there's a general script written, which specifies something like "Column B of row 5 should have this kind of formatting" etc.
**2.** The reason I want this is, because on the drawing, some numbers shown like `15.0` are appearing as `15.00` on the Excel sheet, and this is incorrect, because the number of zeros is an indication of the coarseness, which in Mechanical engineering terms is an important factor to consider.
**3.** Out of curiosity: How in the world does Excel allow us to enter something like `w 9.2` into a numeric field? Shouldn't it force it to be a text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How can I see the scripting done for this worksheet**

The behaviour you're experiencing is probably due to data validation on cells, which you can inspect by selecting one of the cells and then, on the Ribbon, `Data -> Data Validation`.

**2. The reason I want this...**

Not sure what your question is.

**3. Out of curiosity...**

Excel allows custom number formats which can display a text prefix and/or suffix to a numeric value.

[image: Excel Format Cells dialog box]

Comment: Thanks. In question 2 what I meant was that in the SolidEdge drawing, a dimension is shown as `15.0` in the drawing; but when exported to Excel, the dimension is shown as `15.00` in Excel. I did not want the number of zeros to mismatch.  And for question 3, the cell isn't shown as `Custom`. It strangely is a `Number` cell.

Comment: Turns out that for question 2, it was because the "Format cells > Number" format was set to "Number", which was why even though the number was `15`, it got displayed as `15.00`. Would've worked out better if SolidEdge set the field to text instead of number.